# Debian 11 frozen after login in

Tags: linux, debian, freeze, gui

I'm not a very experienced Debian or Linux user. I installed Debian 11 on my HP Probook and it worked perfectly for a long time.

All of a sudden, it started to freeze after in logged in. When i say "it freezes", it's more like some application starts automatically, breaks, and then prevents me from doing (almost) anything. There is a little gray rectangle at the center of the screen which looks like the "active" and blocking application, and the rest of the screen is grayed out.

[image: Frozen screen]

The mouse can move, but I cannot right or left click, especially on the top bar to logoff or start the configuration panel, I can't <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to start an application (or any other shortcut i know). The only thing that works is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> which allows me to display a terminal. I ran `top` command, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Try : (1) [answer1](https://superuser.com/a/1700847/8672), (2) [answer2](https://superuser.com/a/1570429/8672), (3) [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/972170/kali-linux-booting-issue-freeze-at-login-page).

Comment: Had already found those pages and tried the solutions but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried a BIOS update (if one exists) ? I would also look at the disk SMART data and also run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) overnight. Do [these keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31818/what-to-do-when-a-linux-desktop-freezes) resolve the freeze?